# How to connect/link input with Ng Zorro Table (Create search table)

Tags: angular8, ng-zorro-antd

I wish to create a search feature in my NG ZORRO table by linking/connect nz-input with nz-table. Is is possible to do so? Or is there any other methods to do so?

```
<uic-page>
<p>user-details works!</p>
<nz-input-group [nzSuffix]="suffixIconSearch">
  <input type="text" nz-input placeholder="input search text" />
</nz-input-group>
<ng-template #suffixIconSearch>
  <i nz-icon nzType="search"></i>
</ng-template>

<nz-table #basicTable [nzData]="listOfData">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of basicTable.data">
      <td>{{ data.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.age }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.address }}</td>
      <td>
        <a>Action 一 {{ data.name }}</a>
        <nz-divider nzType="vertical"></nz-divider>
        <a>Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</nz-table>
```

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jq2a4l?file=src/app/app.component.ts) should work fine

Just make an event on the input and change the data based on that 
also make sure you make copy of the data (if the search is client-side) to avoid lose the data

Comment: @JK Ainz Welcome. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you for replying.